# What actually happens when Spaceship operator is overwritten in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators, comparison-operators, spaceship-operator

I am new to Ruby. Can someone kindly explain how the <=> method works in the following program. How is the 'other' parameter being used below?

```
class Age
  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
  @value = value
  end

  def <=> (other) # What is actually happening here...
  self.value <=> other.value # ..and here?
  end

end

a = Age.new(7)
b = Age.new(3)
c = Age.new(9)

d = [a, b, c]
puts d.sort
```

Comment: Read this http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html

Comment: But comparable isn't being used here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with `d.sort`. `d` is an array, so you should read about [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort). The documentation says that sorting "will be done using the `<=>` operator". That means when sorting the array it will repeatedly evaluate `x <=> y` where `x` and `y` are different elements of `d`, in order to determine which elements are bigger/smaller.

Operators in Ruby are a little tricky, because they're actually method calls in disguise. `x <=> y` is just a different way of writing `x.<=>(y)`. That is, `x` has a method named `<=>` which is being passed `y` as an argument. Since the elements of `d` are instances of the `Age` class, `Age` needs to define the instance method `<=>`. So when you see `def <=> (other)`, this is really no different from a normal method definition (`def foo(other)`) but with a different method name.

Now that we're defining `<=>` for `Age` instances, what should the method actually do? Well each `Age` object stores a `@value`, so intuitively `Age#<=>` should compare the `@value`s. That's what `self.value <=> other.value` does. This works because `value` returns a `Fixnum`, and luckily [`Fixnum#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) is built into Ruby to do the proper comparison.

For an example of what's going on behind the scenes, we can try sorting arrays containing values that we don't know how to compare:

```
[Age.new(3), 4].sort
# NoMethodError: undefined method `value' for 4:Fixnum
[4, Age.new(3)].sort
# ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Age failed
```

This shows how sorting different types leads to different `<=>` methods being called.

Comment: Hello Max. Thank you for your explanation. I now have an idea of what's actually going on.